# Map document to object

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
public void SearchForDate(String date) {
Information object = new Information();
List<Information> list = new ArrayList<Information>();
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(eq("date", date)).iterator();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(cursor.next().toJson());
    }
}
```

Hi, I want inserting the cursor.next().toJson() information on a new object of the information class, how I could do it? the cursor just return a String...

```
public void BuscarPorPalabra(String date) {
    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(eq("date", date)).iterator();
    basicBOE b = new basicBOE();
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
       Document element = cursor.next();
       b.setDepartament(element.getString("departament"));
       b.setText(element.getString("text"));
       b.setTitle(element.getString("title"));
       list.add(b);
    }
}
```

I got it , but I now have a new problem, the last item overwrite the other object of the list and have a list with 64 same items...

Comment: looking for JsonObjectMapper..are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to iterate the resultset and map the `Document` to your object.

```
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
     Document document = cursor.next();
     Information object = new Information();
     object.setSomeField(document.getString("somefield"));
}
```

Comment: Some result give me this error:  java.util.NoSuchElementException

Comment: Can you please add a document from your collection and updated code ? The field you are trying to map is not in your result set is the cause of the exception.

Comment: Move basicBOE b = new basicBOE(); inside the loop.

Comment: Np. Please read here on how to name in java. www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html