# In MongoDB how to print document in the form of key=value pairs from a java client after getting all documents in a List?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

In MongoDB how to print document in the form of key=value pairs from a java client after getting all documents in a List?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb");
    MongoCollection<Document> coll = database.getCollection("criminal");
    if (coll != null) {
    List<Document> foundDocument = coll.find().into(new ArrayList<Document>());
    Iterator<Document> itr = foundDocument.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {

    //System.out.println(itr.next());
    //here toString() method is overriden in Document so output is displaying
       }
     }
```

Comment: Document is a set of key-value pairs. Here why are you converting to List ( coll.find().into(new ArrayList<Document>());) ?

Comment: suppose im getting 10 Documents and i want them to transfer to another layer so i used List for it.

Comment: Why are you printing them ? What is your use case ? Are you testing something ?

Comment: I want to forward it to view layer. suppose i have 10 documents with 5 filelds each (like name,number,city....),I want to print 2 fields(name and city only) how?

Comment: Take a look at this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/q/42031247/2683814

Comment: Thanks @Veeram working :)